# Faced unknown error using pdftotext utility

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, jspdf, pdftotext

I used a pdftotext utility (ubuntu-14.04) to convert pdf to text in my project.
Recently I've recieved a new-version pdf file and when I do convertation I'm getting some strange error like:

Syntax Error (251355): Unknown compression method in flate stream

Syntax Error (483658): Unknown compression method in flate stream

Syntax Error (251355): Unknown compression method in flate stream
...

what it could be? google didnt give me an answer.

also,
with help of pdfinfo utility I examed two pdf files: new-version file and an old one, which havent threw any errors.
output is same for both files except those two strings:

- new-version file      Producer:       jsPDF 1.0.0-trunk
- old pdf               Producer:       jsPDF 0.9.0rc2

I searched about jsPDF, it's a client side tool to generate pdf files.
Could a new version of it cause an error I got? How to manage with it?Any ideas?

Comment: also I tried a PDFminer scripts to convert new file and ebook-convert utility from colibre.same results.

Comment: Not great error messages! `Syntax Error (251355)` means that the first error is occurring at byte offset 251355 in the PDF file. There should be dictionary delimited by '<<' ... '>>' at that point in the file that presumably contains /Filter and /DecodeParms entries that are not supported by pdftotext

Comment: Can I send you that pdf file to take a look on it?

Comment: if you can, please add a link to the PDF

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4366002/test.pdf

Comment: That's just using simple Flate compression. Very common and widely supported. Should work within anything. Latest jsPDF is 1.1.135. I'd suggest upgrading. If that doesn't work, a bug report might be in order.

Comment: upgrading like what?pdftotext util ?

Comment: @Any_92. It's jsPDF that I'm suspicious of. Btw, I've also I've noticed that pdftk can repair the pdf: `pdftk test.pdf output fixed.pdf uncompress compress`

Comment: have you tried to extract a text from this pdf with a help of pdftotext or pdfminer?

Comment: pdftotext yes, version  0.24.5. pdfminor, no, but I'm also getting uncompress errors with equivalent Perl tools

Comment: sorry,I haven't noticed your comment above. ok I'll try.thank you.